# How to translate "against yourself"?

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

Is the following translation of "against yourself" correct?

> contra te ipsum

I'd like to use the phrase "against yourself" in the following context: "to fight against yourself", "it's you against yourself", and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contra te ipsum is fine. It should work just about anywhere a particular verb doesn't demand a different preposition.

Example:

> Quandiu igitur expugnator libidinis eris, tandiu pro me contra te ipsum judex eris.
>
> Augustine, Contra Julianum 3.44.

So then, for as long as you will be a conqueror of inordinate desire, you will be a judge [ruling] in my favor against your own self.

Comment: This is not related to your answer itself (which did earn my vote), but I just wanted to say that I'm very happy to see a new knowledgeable user like you find their way to our site. I hope you will find the site both useful and interesting! If you have any questions or ideas, or you just feel like chatting in or about Latin, you are more than welcome to our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm).